# After casting Sub Class to Base Class, type is still Sub class

Tags: c#

In the code below, I cast a sub class into a base class, yet the get type shows that it is still an instance of the sub class. What is going on here?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car c1 = new Car { m = "M", c = "C" };

            Machine m1 = (Machine)c1;

            Console.WriteLine(m1.GetType());//ConsoleApplication.Car

        }
    }

    public class Machine
    {
        public string m;
    }

    public class Car : Machine
    {
        public string c;
    }


}
```

Comment: What if the base class was `abstract`? Would it make sense to have an instance of the base class then?

Comment: @retailcoder indeed, or if you casted it to an `interface`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the object itself *is* an instance of the subclass. You're merely pointing at it with a base class reference.

Answer (score 4):

Casting doesn't change the type of the instance.  Casting changes the type of the reference.

Converting changes the type of the instance.

Comment: How do I Convert an instance of car into an instance of machine?

Comment: Implement a method on Car which returns a Machine.  Within the method, new up a Machine instance and return it.  Machine myMachine = myCar.ToMachine();

Answer (score 1):

```
m1.GetType()
```

This doesn't look at the declared type of the variable, it runs the `GetType()` function on the object itself.  And the object itself knows what type it is, regardless of what you cast it to for any particular variable.